# Compute the distance between two line endpoints with intersecting linestrings

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Assume that we have three line-segments, each represented as `linestring`s in PostGIS.
What I intend to compute is the distance between y and x. What I am doing is as follows:

```
with recursive len_rec as (
    select
        st_length(geometry) as length, 0 as depth, id
    from A
    union all      
    select
        len_rec.length + st_length(A.geometry), len_rec.depth + 1, A.id
    from A
    join b
    on A.id = B.id2
    join len_rec
    where B.id1 = len_rec.id
)
select * from len_rec;
```

Intuitively, I am doing this:

- computing the length of each line segment using `st_length`
- summing them together

There are two tables in the database, one is `A` containing the `geometry` and the `id` of the object and the other is `B` containing connections between two entities `id1` and `id2`. The table `B` can be inferred from table `A` using the `st_intersects` function, however, I have included it for simplicity.

However, the final result contains the extra part of the red-line which is not correct. How can I change the SQL code to compute a correct answer? Is it possible to do so?

[image: Example image of three line strings y--z, z--w and a--x]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! Have you considered using pgrouting ? https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/index.html

Comment: @J.Monticolo No, would check it to see how it works.